# WordPress widget outputs a unwanted number

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I made a WordPress widget that is only supposed to display an image but is displaying a number also. I don't know why this happens.

Widget output code:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    ?>
        <img src="<?= $instance['image'] ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    <?php
}
```

Widget area it's in:

```
<div class="spotlight">
    <?= dynamic_sidebar('header') ?>
</div>
```

Unwanted output (the image is correct but it also prints a "1"):

[image]

Any help on how to fix this?

Comment: Nothing changes. @TopologicalSort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
<div class="spotlight">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('header'); ?>
</div>
```

The `<?=` short open tag means `<?php echo` and `dynamic_sidebar` function returns true (which is converted to number in your case) if widget sidebars exists.

Comment: Thanks, you're a legend!